# Can You Help Me Translate?

Tags: translation, traditional-characters

[image: notebook1]

[image: notebook2]

Can you help me translate these notebok pages please

Comment: request submitted to https://bkrs.info/taolun/thread-315008.html

Comment: bottom 4 lines recognized, "is this a soup, if so, then very nice"

Comment: link in comment #1 changed by bkrs to https://bkrs.info/taolun/thread-314961.html

Answer (score 3):

## 1st picture:

咱们可以把地下室<s>**改为**</s>**变成**(not sure)
体操室，乒乓球室，玩跑跑
跳跳**的**(not sure)
We can alter the to basement to a gymnastics room, a table tennis room, to play and jump there.

A.
地下室的那些大件，我们无法<s>**把**</s>
弄出地下室。是否可以在**南宁生** (not sure) 网上
发布消息，有婴幼儿大件物品**免费** (later inserted word) 送出，
自己负责搬运。

地下室的那些大件，我们无法弄出地下室。是否可以在 **？？？** 网上发布消息，有婴幼儿大件物品免费送出，自己负责搬运。
We can't get the big items in the basement out. Should we post a message on the **???** website, that we have some free big infant items, but need to move it by self.

清理后：①体操②乒乓球

Left (after cleaning): 1. gymnastics 2. ping pong (table tennis)

B.
娱乐室的一侧衣帽间存放了两张
床垫和铁床<s>**执**</s>架，基本已满。

娱乐室的一侧衣帽间存放了两张床垫和铁床架，基本已满。
There are two mattresses and iron bed frames stored in one side of the recreation room, almost full.

①另一侧的物品是否打算捐出？
Should the items on the other side intended to be donated?

②睡房的三张海<s>**执**</s>绵垫捐出吧，床垫
已经够多了。<s>**睡房**</s>衣帽间打算整理一下，放衣物。

睡房的三张海绵垫捐出吧，床垫已经够多了。衣帽间打算整理一下，放衣物。
There are enough mattresses, we can donate three sponge mats in the bedroom. The cloakroom is going to be sorted to store clothes.

<s>**执**</s>: about to write 垫 and then deleted.

## 2nd picture:

用外卖饭盒的铁线做**个** (not sure for it's blocked) 挂勾 (should be 挂钩 here)
Make a hook with the iron wire (means the handle here) of the takeaway box.

周三晚餐 (written as 歺 here)：
Dinner for Wednesday:

1.煎荷包蛋，三只
fried poached egg, of three.
2.滚牛肉丸，10粒
rolled beef balls, of ten.
3.蚝油炒西兰花，青豆粒
fried broccoli with oyster sauce, and green beans.
4.煮饭
cook rice.

Comment: Oh I was about to write and saw your post, then finding no need for me, hhhh.

Answer (score 1):

“？” in the parenthesis means the character that I am unable to recognize currently. One "?" represents one unrecognized character.

Page 1:

咱们可以把地下室改成体操室，乒乓球室，(*？跑跑跳跳*, run and jump)

We can refurnish the basement to the gymnastics room or the table tennis room. (Not sure about the last few words in this sentence, so I just provide my guess above in parentheses)

A.
地下室的那些大件，我们无法弄出地下室。是否可以在（？？？）网上（？？？？）? 有婴幼儿大件物流免费送出，自己负责搬运。清理后：1. 体操 2. 乒乓球

We aren't able to move the bulky packages out the basement. Can we ... online ...? Free large infant products, but we aren't responsible for moving them out. After removing them: 1. gymnastics 2. ping-pong

B. 
(I can only recognize some keywords from this section for now.)

衣帽间（cloakroom）

床垫（mattress）

床架（bed frames）

Page 2: (This is a recipe)

周三晚餐：

Dinner for Wednesday：

1.煎荷包蛋 Fried eggs

2.滚牛肉丸  10粒 Making the beef ball， 10 counts

3.纯油炒西兰花、青豆粒 Fried broccoli and peas with oil

4.煮饭 Boil the rice

Answer (score 0):

蚝油炒西兰花。“蚝油” is some sort of oil which is made from oyster.